# Количество байт, читаемых из TCP-сокета

Tags: c, tcp-ip, unix, c++, сокет

Всем добрый день!
Уважаемые спецы, не могли бы вы уточнить для меня понятие промежуточной буфферизации в сети, а так же как она сказывается на количестве байт, считываемых из сокета. Возможна ли ситуация, когда клиент системным вызовом *write()* записывает в сокет, к примеру, 1024 байта, а вызов *read()* на сервере при чтении этого сокета так же ожидает 1024 байта,  однако *read()* возвращает данные порциями : 1000, 24 байта, или данных прийдет ровно столько, сколько было отправлено? (никакие сигналы вызов *read()* не прерывают, сервер сокет не закрывает, сокет блокируемый).

Comment: Придёт столько, сколько отправлено, поскольку tcp гарантирует правильность доставки (или всё пришло, или ошибка). Вопрос -- когда придёт. Надо смотреть блокирующее/неблокирующее чтение (O_NONBLOCK, MSG_DONTWAIT в recv). При блокирующем чтении возможна ситуация, когда хвост будет получен при закрытии соединения (или потерян, если программа так написана).

Comment: А вот похоже наврал немного, потому что про recv, recvfrom и recvmsg написано, 

      Все  эти  функции  обычно возвращают уже доступные данные вплоть до запрошенного объема, и не ждут, пока появятся данные полной запрошенной длины.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данные в большинстве случаев придут все. Но разбить может в абсолютно произвольных (на первый взгляд) соотношениях. Но вот порядок байт - гарантирован.

В быстрых сетях (например через wifi) размер пакета может быть очень большим и если посылать небольшие пакеты (до 1000 байт), то может сложиться впечатление, что пакеты не разбиваются. Но это не так. Я недавно исправлял такое приложение, которое надеялось, что пакеты не будут разбиваться и время от времени подглючивало.

То есть, можно верить в то, что

- если бы все байты занумеровать, то порядок их на приемной стороне не поменяется
- данные либо будут доставлены, либо будет сгенерирована ошибка (таймаут к примеру).

Comment: @KoVadim, тоесть, послав tcp-пакет размером в 1024 байта я могу считать его кусками?

Comment: @margosh разумеется. @KoVadim я уже писал tcp -- протокол надёжной доставки. Данные приходят все в правильном порядке, или Вы получаете в коде возврата какого-то вызова ошибку. С udp -- иначе. Там пакеты могут теряться или менять порядок поступления.

Comment: мне как раз хотелось бы принимать пакеты целиком, и я думала что это возможно, используя системный вызов *read()*, в котором, по идее, программа блокируется до получения указанного количества байт, или признака конца файла (а в данном случае закрытия сокета)

Comment: read может попытаться прочитать пакет целиком. Посмотрите на [это](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943434/recv-with-msg-nonblock-and-msg-waitall). Но его может прервать сигнал. Поэтому, хотя и кажется, что проще было бы, что бы они читали все, но на практике как раз наоборот.
И второе. Если допустить, что у нас есть send и recv, которые гарантированно отправляют/получают указанный блок, то отправив так send([1,2,3]), send([4,5,6]) и прочитав recv(2),recv(2),recv(2), то каждый вернет соответственно [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]. (я сделал запись немного условной, но это только для понимания процесса

Comment: в моем случае read никакими сигналами, кроме как сигналами выхода из программы не прерывается - это тест, который в цикле посылает запросы серверу и ждет ответов. Ответы - произвольной длины. Сориентироваться, закончил ли сервер ответ на предыдущее сообщение можно только по длине вернувшихся данных - если они равны размеру запрашиваемых на чтение, значит вероятнее всего нужно ждать новой порции, если меньше - можно слать новый запрос. Если при считывании я получаю вовсе не то количество байт, которое прислал сервер - я забью его запросами

Comment: @margosh, напишите свою функцию, которая будет читать n байт и возвращаться раньше, только в 2-х случаях (закрытие сокета и прерывание по сигналу). 

По сути она должна возвращать 1) количество успешно прочитанных байт 2) флаги прерывания и конца потока.

Можно еще сделать аналог fgets().

В простейшем случае это несложно. 

Если будете бороться за эффективность, то придется самой делать всю буферизацию ввода в стиле FILE из libc.

Comment: @margosh А что значит "пакеты целиком"? У Вас есть труба, по которой Вы гоните поток байт. Изначально у потока есть начало, есть конец, но нет никаких промежуточных маркеров. Лучше из этого и исходить.

Comment: В целом, нельзя полагаться, что если запросили прочитать 10 байт, то он прочитает их. Может 1000 раз подряд читать 10 байт, а один раз прочитать 9 байт. Поэтому нужно делать цикл на чтение, и если пришло мало байт, то проанализировать ситуацию и дочитать.

Comment: @margosh, мой комментарий (про функцию n байт)  получился "асинхронным".

--

Ответ на ваш комментарий (Ответы - произвольной длины.):

Пусть сервер в начале ответа пишет его длину (в фиксированном формате). Все станет просто (особенно если сделать свою буферизацию).

Кстати, не сразу, так послезавтра, с прерываниями чтения по сигналам Вы обязательно столкнетесь. Так что обдумывайте этот момент сразу.

Comment: почему не сможете? просто нужно ещё раз читать. Длину данных, которые нужно получить вы ведь знаете. где то так

    char[] buf;
    r = 0;
    l = len;
    do {
       int x = recv(fd, buf + r, l);
       if (x == 0) {ups, socket closed, do sm break;}
       if (x == -1) {some error happened. go; break;}
       r += x;
       l -= x;
    } while (r < len);

Это набросок. Дальше корректируйте под свои требования

Comment: @margosh что то странное говорите.

Comment: @avp, там где необходимо, я учитываю прерывания сигналами, здесь же это ни к чему, это просто тест. По поводу добавления какого-либо признака в ответе - уже предлагала, но мне пока запретили такие изменения вносить, так как на подобное прийдется реагировать не мною написанным клиентам.  
@KoVadim, ну да, теоретически длину данных учесть можно, только вот запросов около 1000, соответственно и длина данных варьируется в широких пределах для каждого запроса, поэтому меня совсем не радует перспектива подобной проверки длины.

Comment: @margosh, если некие клиенты шлют логические посылки неизвестной длины, то это очевидная архитектурная ошибка, которую все равно надо исправлять.

По поводу *непосредствено вопроса*.

Данные (N байт), записанные в сокет одним write() могут быть прочитаны как одним, так и несколькими read() (вообще говоря непредсказуемо). Обратное (несколько write() - один read()) - тоже верно.

Другими словами данные в TCP сокете это однородный поток байт без какой-либо структуры (@alexlz и @KoVadim писали об этом).

--

В принципе по тому же сокету можно гнать еще один поток (OOB данные). Иногда может спасти

Comment: @margosh Добавляйте перед блоком данных его длину, и Ваши волосы будут длинными и шелковистыми.